# can ngOptions call a function to get display text?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `select` tag that I'm binding to an array of radio station objects using AngularJS.  My object has the following properties:

```js
{
    id: 'WXYZ',
    name: 'Radio Station Name (optional)',
    frequency: '89.7 FM'
}
```

I'd like each element in the dropdown to show "{id} - {name} - {frequency}" as the display text, but since the name property is optional, I'd like to avoid double dashes in the event that an object has no value for its name.

I was able to get this working:

```html
<select ng-model="StationPreference" ng-options="s.id+ ' - ' + s.name + ' - ' + s.frequency for s in stations">
    <option value="">-- select --</option>
</select>
```

What are the rules/guidelines/best practices for calling a function inside ng-options?  I'd like to do something like `getDisplayText(s)` -- what makes the expression "valid for angular"?  does the function have to be defined inside the scope? Can it be any externally defined function?  Is this the best approach for the desired functionality?

Comment: You can try `+ s.name || 'No name supplied' +`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to call a function inside ng-options?

Short answer: yes. (A quick test would have also answered this for you.)

Longer answer: `ng-options` allows you to specify any arbitrary expression (as long as it is valid for Angular) in both the `label` and `value` slots of the options comprehension (see [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect)). This means you can specify a function available on the scope to produce your `label` string.

**Update:**

The value used by `ng-options` as the label is generated by consuming the string you provided and passing it to `$parse` to generate an evaluable expression which will be called later. This expression is then run against the `scope` with the additional local values from the looping to actually generate the string which is displayed. The expression can do basically anything that you might put in an `{{ interpolation }}` (interpolations are done with `$parse` too, unless I'm mistaken), which can include concatenating strings, calling functions visible on the scope (which could actually exist on a parent scope and be inherited), running Angular filters (e.g. `lowercase` or `json`), etc.

In terms of best practices, I would say that your initial display of `s.id+ ' - ' + s.name + ' - ' + s.frequency` is probably fine as an expression rather than extracting it to a function on the scope. However, it is mildly complex and adding the condition you desire would definitely push it over the edge to a function (even though it's possible as an expression using a ternary). In general if the display logic is complex or if the same logic is used in multiple places, it should be extracted to a function, or even a filter depending on how generic it is.

Comment: Thanks @squid314 - I had already looked at the docs.  `label: The result of this expression will be the label for <option> element. The expression will most likely refer to the value variable` wasn't clear to me, plus I had meant to ask more than a simple "is this possible". I've clarified my question.

Answer (score 13):

this worked for me:

```
<select ng-model="myForm.car"
        ng-options="obj.id as genName(obj.id,obj.name) for obj in myForm.options">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
</select>


$scope.myForm.options = [
    { id : "nissan", name: "Nissan" },
    { id : "toyota", name: "Toyota" },
    { id : "fiat"  , name: "Fiat" }
];

$scope.genName = function(id,name) {
    return id + ' ' + name;
}
```

Comment: your solution is work for text but i want image along with text
for ex. i have list of countries and i want to show it with flag so how can i show it?

Comment: CSS/HTML does not allow for an image or a background image to be shown in an option. It's a limitation of the specs. You'll have to use a custom  directive, e.g. https://angularjsaz.blogspot.com/2015/11/angularjs-select-option-with-image.html

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hidden in the documentation but it can be achieved easily.

In your case, it is the syntax documented as :

```
select as label for value in array
```

And so for you need:

```
<select ng-model="StationPreference" ng-options="s as getDisplayText(s) for s in stations">
    <option value="">-- select --</option>
</select>
```